# iOS App: Terminated due to memory issue [Related to swiftSlowAlloc or UIImage]

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, memory-leaks, uiimage

Currently I am facing a memory issue problem in building iOS app. I checked for Memory leaks using Instruments. I found that there is one kind of leaks that keeps on showing up named swift_slowAlloc, which I don't have idea about. An snippet of the error is given below.

[image: Memory Leaks]

Another reason I think could happen is due to loading of several UIImages in my app. Just to provide a background, I take various portions of an original image in my app and do some processing on them. However, I don't need to keep the images for further calculations. I used autoreleasepool to release the UIImage; but I doubt that it is working. An example is given below:

```
   @autoreleasepool {

        UIImage *imageResized = MatToUIImage(resized28);

        // MARK: Send resized28 to CNN and get the output. Fill the dict then

        NSString *CNNScore;
        CNNScore = [myclass CNNfloat:imageResized W1:W1 W2:W2 Wf1:Wf1 Wf2:Wf2 B1:B1 B2:B2 Bf1:Bf1 Bf2:Bf2];

        imageResized = nil;
        xtn = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:xt];
        xbn = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:xb];
        ytn = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:yt];
        ybn = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:yb];

        symbol = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", CNNScore];
        symtype = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [scoreDic objectForKey: symbol]];

        numberInDict = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", n];


        inToMaroof = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: xtn, xbn, ytn, ybn, symbol,symtype, nil];

        [toMaroof setObject: inToMaroof
                     forKey: numberInDict];
        }
    }
```

Can someone suggest anything on this issue?

Comment: Any updates with this?

We see something similar.  My hypothesis is that iOS shuts down apps that get memory hungry in a short period of time.

Answer (score 0):

These are some possible causes that may cause a memory leak in your program even if using ARC:

1. You set a strong reference to a parent in a child object. This causes a retain cycle.
2. You set a strong reference to a delegate in an interface.
3. You forgot to release an object when you do a toll-free bridging after transferring ownership.
4. You forgot to set a weak reference to objects you passed in a block.